# Fragment (Blank) doesn't scroll to bottom

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm starting programming with Android and I have created a little app for character sheet. I have completed all the app but I have a problem: my fragment doesn't scroll to the bottom of page. this is used in a fragment. 
This is my xml, I hope someone can help me. I'm stuck since 3 day

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView_fm_2">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" >

            <TextView
                android:text="ABILITY"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colornero"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:id="@+id/textView8" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" SCOR "
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colornero"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:id="@+id/textView9" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" Ability\n MODIF "
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colornero"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:id="@+id/textView10" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" TEMP.\n SCO "
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colornero"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:id="@+id/textView11" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" TEM.\n MODIF "
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colornero"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:id="@+id/textView12" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colornero"

            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <TextView
                android:text="Strength"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colornero"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:id="@+id/textView7" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/strength_score"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/strength_modif"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_width="13dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/strength_tem_scor"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/strength_tem_modi" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            <TextView
                android:text="Dexterity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colornero"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:id="@+id/textView2" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/dexterity_score"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/dexterity_modif"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/dexterity_tem_scor"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_width="13dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/dexterity_tem_modif" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:text="Constitution"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colornero"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:id="@+id/textView3" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/constitution_score"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/constitution_modi"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/constitution_tem_sco"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/constitution_tem_modif" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:text="Intelligence"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colornero"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:id="@+id/textView4" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/intelligence_score"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/Intelligence_modif"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/Intelligence_tem_sco"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/Intelligence_tem_modi" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:text="Wisdom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:textColor="@color/colornero"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/wisdom_sco"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/wisdom_modif"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/wisdom_tem_sco"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/wisdom_tem_modi" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:text="Charisma"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
                android:textColor="@color/colornero"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:id="@+id/textView6" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/charisma_score"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/charisma_modif"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/charisma_tem_sco"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/charisma_tem_modif" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>    
    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/MODIFIER"
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/space"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        >
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colornero"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sav. Throws"
                android:background="@drawable/back"

                />

            <TextView
                android:text="Total"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colornero"
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                />

            <TextView
                android:text=" Base\n Save"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colornero"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                />

            <TextView
                android:text=" Ability\n Modif."
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colornero"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                />

            <TextView
                android:text=" Magic\n Modif."
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colornero"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                />

            <TextView
                android:text=" Misc.\n Modif."
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colornero"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                />

            <TextView
                android:text=" Temp.\n Modif."
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colornero"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView18"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            >

            <TextView
                android:text="     Fortitude \n (Constitution)"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colornero"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView19" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/tempra_tot"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/tempra_base_save"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_width="13dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/tempra_ability_mod"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/tempra_magic_mod" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/tempra_misc_mod" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/tempra_temp_mod" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            >

            <TextView
                android:text="     Reflex \n (Dexterity)"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colornero"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView20" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/reflex_tot"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/reflex_base_save"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_width="13dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/reflex_ability_mod"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/reflex_magic_mod" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/reflex_misc_mod" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/reflex_temp_mod" />
        </TableRow>


        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            >

            <TextView
                android:text="      Will \n (Wisdom)"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colornero"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView21" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/will_tot"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/will_base_save"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_width="13dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/will_ability_mod"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/will_magic_mod" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/will_misc_mod" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/will_temp_mod" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>    
</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

And this is not all the code because is too long.

```
public class TwoFragment extends Fragment {

    EditText et;
    EditText et1;
    EditText et2;
    EditText et3;
    EditText et4;
    EditText et5;

    public TwoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

        SharedPreferences setting = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PRESS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
et =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.strength_score);
        et1 =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.strength_modif);
        et2 =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.strength_tem_scor);
        et3 =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.strength_tem_modi);

        et4 =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dexterity_score);
        et5 =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dexterity_modif);

    et.setText(setting.getString("value", ""));
        et1.setText(setting.getString("value1", ""));
        et2.setText(setting.getString("value2", ""));
        et3.setText(setting.getString("value3", ""));

        et4.setText(setting.getString("value4", ""));
        et5.setText(setting.getString("value5", ""));
            return view;
    }
    public void onStop( ){
        super.onStop();
        if(et.getText() != null)
            if (et1.getText() !=null)
                if (et2.getText() !=null)
                    if (et3.getText() !=null)
                        if (et4.getText() !=null)
                            if (et5.getText() !=null)
SharedPreferences setting = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PRESS", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = setting.edit();
            editor.putString("value", et.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("value1", et1.getText().toString());
                        editor.putString("value2", et2.getText().toString());
                        editor.putString("value3", et3.getText().toString());

                            editor.putString("value4", et4.getText().toString());
                            editor.putString("value5", et5.getText().toString());
  editor.apply();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my manager of the different fragment.

```
public class character2 extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.character2);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // handle arrow click here
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish(); // close this activity and return to preview activity (if there is any)
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "One");
    adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "Two");
    adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "Three");
    adapter.addFrag(new fourFragment(), "Four");
    adapter.addFrag(new FiveFragment(), "Five");
    adapter.addFrag(new SixFragment(), "Six");
    adapter.addFrag(new SevenFragment(), "Seven");
    adapter.addFrag(new Ninrfragment(), "Eight");
    adapter.addFrag(new TenFragment(), "Nine");
    adapter.addFrag(new EightFragment(), "Ten");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I just copy/pasted your layout, it works fine, the scrollview works correctly. Nothing seems to be prevent the scroll event.

Comment: Are you using this inside of a Fragment? As @Filo said, the ScrollView seems to be find if it's just copied and pasted into a layout, but you mention Fragments so maybe showing the rest of your code and how you load up this layout would help.

Comment: Hi i have post rest of the code someone can help with this problem.